# How to prove that $|f'(z)|^2=\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dv}{dy}\right)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone explain to me why $|f'(z)|^2=\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dv}{dy}\right)^2$,

I have found $|f'(z)|^2=f'(z)$ multiplied by its conjugate. By why is this equal?

Thank you for the responses :)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: That is the definition of absolute value in the complex plane.... if $z = x+iy, |z| = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}  = \sqrt {z\bar z}$

Comment: This looks funky to me.  Shouldn't it be $(du/dx)^2+(d\color{blue}{u}/dy)^2$?

Comment: Those should be partial derivatives.

Comment: Which I don't really know how to make.  Still should be both $u$ (or both $v$) in the "numerators".

Answer (score 1):

- *I think there are a lot of typo in your question* (*already mentioned in comment by @Oscar Lanzi & @Cameron Williams*). *I am going to answer your question after the proper correction*.

${}$

Here $~f(z)=u+iv~$.

So $~f'(z)=u_x+iv_x=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}~$.

Hence $~\overline{f'(z)}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}~$

Therefore $~|f'(z)|^2=f'(z)\cdot \overline{f'(z)}=\left[\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right]\cdot\left[\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right]=\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2~.\tag1$

Now if $~f(z)~$ be an analytic function of $~z~$, then by Cauchy-Riemann equation, $~\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}~$ and $~\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}~$.

From equation $(1)$, $~|f'(z)|^2=\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(-\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2~$.